# Is is allowed, by COM rules, to do reference count per Interface instance?

Tags: com, oledb

I'm getting a crash from Excel while it's using an OLE DB provider I'm writing, and the reason seems to be, after digging through some disassembly, due to it trying to call a method on an instance of IDBInfo which the provider as already deleted (as its reference count went down to 0).

Now, in this provider, every call to QueryInterface on any of my interfaces *always* returns a new (C++) object (which delegates all IUnknown methods to a common object which represents the COM object as a whole, except in the case of IUnknown, so as to allow identity checks, and follow COM rules), each of which maintains it's own reference count.

For example, given a 'live' IUnknown A from my provider (and assuming QueryInterface succeeds),

```
ISomeInterface* B;
ISomeInterface* C;
A->QueryInterface(IID_ISomeInterface, (void**)&B);
// B refcount = 1.

A->QueryInterface(IID_ISomeInterface, (void**)&C);
// C refcount = 1, B refcount unchanged.

C->Release();
// C refcount = 0, C is destroyed, B refcount unchanged.

C->SomeMethod(); // Will crash as C has been destroyed, even though there is an outstanding 'live' ISomeInterface instance on the same object (i.e. B).
```

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx , this seems like a valid, if strange, implementation.

Am I actually breaking COM rules here?

Comment: Yes, reference counting is per-interface, so QueryInterface can return a new object, except when queried for IUnknown. Make sure you observe the other QI rules: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682521(v=vs.85).aspx They are easier to implement with one object. PS: If you're working with visual Studio and C++ I suggest you use ATL which does all that for you once you understand how it works. It's easier to make errors in this domain.

Comment: These interface pointers are called tear-offs, they're perfectly valid. One thing that is not valid is making each new queried interface pointer have a separate state, e.g. if SomeMethod() has side effects, they should affect the object in the same manner whether invoked by B or C. Inter-apartment QueryInterface is allowed to cache interface pointers, so on the other side, B and C can be the same interface pointer (and you'd see a refcount of 2 when both are alive).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way `AddRef` and `Release` are supposed to be treated is as a reference count *on each pointer*. Each time you make a copy of the pointer, you `AddRef`; and each time you stop using the pointer, you `Release`.   Therefore, the object can be destroyed precisely when there are no interface pointers left that point to it.

(In practice this is usually optimized somewhat, e.g. in a situation where you pass the interface pointer to a function that is totally under your control, you might not bother to `AddRef` for the function argument and `Release` when the function returns).

To answer your question: after *the pointer* `C`'s refcount has gone to `0`, it is illegal to do `C->` anything. The pointer `C`'s lifetime has ended, even though the object it pointed to may still exist.

It doesn't make a difference how you implemented the interface, e.g. whether it was backed by a C++ object or whatever. The interface is completely opaque, that's one of the core concepts of COM. The rules say that the client can't make any further calls through that pointer once that pointer's refcount got to `0`.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit sloppy in my working. When I said 'new object' I meant a new C++ object, which delegate all IUnknown methods to another object which was shared by all the interfaces of a give conceptual COM 'object'.

Comment: @Bwman OK, have removed the stuff about aggregation from my post.